# Is this correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many distinct $(a,b,c)$ satisfy $a^2+bc=b^2+ac$ where $a,b,c$ are integers between $1$ and $5$ inclusive. $a(a-c)=b(b-c)$, $a/b=(b-c)/(a-c)=(a+b-c)/(a+b-c)=1$, so $a=b$, so the answer is 25 solutions. My only concern is that there seem to be no restrictions on the variable $c$. Is this ok?

Comment: There are two cases:$$a^{ 2 }+bc-b^{ 2 }-ac=\left( a-b \right) (a+b-c)=0\\ a=b\\ a+b=c$$

Comment: Wouldn't the equation $a=b$ always hold true so the second one would automatically reduce to $2a=c?$

Comment: The question says $(a,b,c)$ are distinct. So you you should use $a+b=c$. Even if they are not distinct, you should use $a=b$ or $a+b=c$ or both. When you use both you get one of the solutions $2b=2a=c$ as you indicated, but don't forget you are asked for distinct values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that from you equation you get $a^2-b^2=ac-bc$ which is $$(a-b)(a+b)=(a-b)c$$

One option is thus $a=b$. Now assume $a\neq b$. Then you get $a+b=c$. And this has infinitely many solutions!

Comment: I don't think you can assume $a$ does not equal $b$, your equation would just transform into $2a=c$, right?

Comment: @Ovi You're mistaken $a\neq b$ means the equation is $2a=c$. If $a\neq b$, $a-b\neq 0$ so we can simplify it, and get $a+b=c$. That is all.

Comment: By the way could you take a look at my other question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407244/not-so-easy-optimization-of-variables/407251?noredirect=1#comment871484_407251